# What is the transfer function of this bandpass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter, band-pass

I have this bandpass filter for which I'm trying to get the transfer function. The amplifier is not idead and has an open-loop gain of 100k and a gain-bandwidth product of 10MHz.

[image: Bandpass filter diagram]

I tried everything but at the end of my calculations what I get is the transfer function of a high pass filter, even though if I simulate this circuit in LTSpice it clearly shows that it is a bandpass filter.
[image]
[image]

I saw a similar circuit online showing a bandpass filter, but it clearly had a lowpass filter after the amplifier circuit:

[image]

Comment: Please post your calculations that result in the transfer function for a high pass filter so we can show you where you made a mistake.

Comment: Hint: for this particlar circuit, you can determine the transfer functions of each section separately and then combine them afterwards. Hint 2: your circuit is not the same as the picture you show. Your circuit does not have R2 and C2. You do get a bandpass curve because the opamp you're using is **not ideal**.

Comment: I've updated the question @Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CR highpass filter has one pole and one zero. The opamp itself has one pole (it doesn't have infinite bandwidth) as indicated by LTSpice:-

[image]

So the transfer function will be in the form \$H(s) = \frac{b_1s}{s^2+a_1s+a_0} \$ which clearly is a transfer function for a bandpass filter.

If you want to avoid this you can give your opamp more bandwidth in LTSpice. This is done by right-clicking on the opamp and then change the GBW to something like 100000Meg: -

[image]

Doing that will give you a frequency response that looks like this: -

[image]

Answer (score -1):

LTSpice keeps into account the 2 poles of the operational amplifier.

That's why you see the Body's plot to bend down after a certain frequency.

Comment: The opamp model op uses only has a single pole.

Answer (score -1):

Well, using the voltage divider formula we can see that:

- $$\text{v}_+\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\cdot\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\tag1$$
- $$\text{v}_-\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\cdot\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)\tag2$$

For an non-ideal opamp we know that \$\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathcal{A}\left(\text{v}_+\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{v}_-\left(\text{s}\right)\right)\$, so:

$$\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathcal{A}\left(\frac{\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\cdot\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)-\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\cdot\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\frac{\mathcal{A}\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}}{1+\frac{\mathcal{A}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}}=\frac{\mathcal{A}\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\text{s}}{\text{R}_2\left(1+\mathcal{A}\right)+\text{R}_3+\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_2\left(1+\mathcal{A}\right)+\text{R}_3\right)\text{s}}\tag3$$

So, we know that:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\mathcal{A}\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\omega}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_2\left(1+\mathcal{A}\right)+\text{R}_3\right)^2+\left(\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_2\left(1+\mathcal{A}\right)+\text{R}_3\right)\omega\right)^2}}\tag4$$

And because of the GBWP, we must write:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\mathcal{A}\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\omega}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_2\left(1+\mathcal{A}\right)+\text{R}_3\right)^2+\left(\text{CR}_1\left(\text{R}_2\left(1+\mathcal{A}\right)+\text{R}_3\right)\omega\right)^2}}&\text{if}\space\omega<2\pi\cdot\text{GBWP}_{\space\left[\text{Hz}\right]}\\
\\
1&\text{if}\space\omega\ge2\pi\cdot\text{GBWP}_{\space\left[\text{Hz}\right]}
\end{cases}
\tag5$$

---

Using your values, we get:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=
\begin{cases}
\frac{100100000\omega}{101001\sqrt{250000+\omega^2}}&\text{if}\space\omega<2\pi\cdot10^7\\
\\
1&\text{if}\space\omega\ge2\pi\cdot10^7
\end{cases}
\tag6$$

Comment: The OP already has (quite easily) found the transfer function for the high-pass behavior. The question is asking about "if I simulate this circuit in LTSpice it clearly shows that **it is a bandpass filter**".